# How to add value from nested dictionary to a player's stats?

Tags: python, project

I've just gone about doing my first python project, and I'm now seeking some python wisdom!

How would you go about adding these values (From the weapons). Well I know to import the module into the other module, but what about adding the 'attack_power'(etc) values to the values of my classes?

So just to get it straight. I would want to += the value from the dictionary weapon that the player has equipped to the stats of the player values?

equipment.py module:

```
weapons = {
'starter_dagger':   {'attack_power': 4,
                     'agility': 10,
                     'luck': 1,
                     'description': 'Assassins starter weapon, used by only the newest members.'},

'starter_staff':    {'spell_power': 8,
                     'attack_power': 4,
                     'luck': 1,
                     'description': 'For the novice wizards.'},

'starter_longsword':    {'attack_power': 12,
                         'agility': -2,
                         'luck': 2,
                         'description': 'Unnecessarily heavy longsword, used to train the novice warriors.'},

'starter_torch':    {'attack_power': 6,
                     'agility': 6,
                     'spell_power': 4,
                     'description': 'To wander and not get lost, this torch will guide you through the darkest of '
                                    'places'},
```

classes.py module:

````
class HeroCharacter:
    def __init__(self, name, health_points, attack_power, spell_power, agility, inventory,
                 level, experience, luck):
        self.name = name
        self.health_points = health_points
        self.attack_power = attack_power
        self.spell_power = spell_power
        self.agility = agility
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.level = level
        self.experience = experience
        self.luck = luck

class Adventurer(HeroCharacter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name=input("Enter your character name: "), health_points=225, attack_power=30,
                         spell_power=0, agility=30, inventory={}, level=1, experience=0, luck=10)

    profession = "Adventurer"

class Wizard(HeroCharacter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name=input("Enter your character name: "), health_points=175, attack_power=10,
                         spell_power=75, agility=0, inventory={}, level=1, experience=0, luck=4)
    profession = "Wizard"

class Warrior(HeroCharacter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name=input("Enter your character name: "), health_points=250, attack_power=60,
                         spell_power=5, agility=15, inventory={}, level=1, experience=0, luck=4)

    profession = "Warrior"

class Assassin(HeroCharacter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name=input("Enter your character name: "), health_points=200, attack_power=35,
                         spell_power=15, agility=40, inventory={}, level=1, experience=0, luck=4)

    profession = "Assassin"```
````

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I might structure it:

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Weapon(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    attack_power: int
    spell_power: int
    agility: int
    luck: int
    description: str


class HeroCharacter:
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        health_points: int,
        attack_power: int,
        spell_power: int,
        agility: int,
        luck: int,
    ):
        self._name = name
        self._health_points = health_points
        self._attack_power = attack_power
        self._spell_power = spell_power
        self._agility = agility
        self._luck = luck
        self._level = 1
        self._experience = 0
        self._weapon = Weapon(
            "unarmed", 0, 0, 0, 0, "You are unarmed."
        )
        self._inventory = []  # What kinds of things go in here?

    def equip(self, weapon: Weapon) -> None:
        # Should the old weapon go into the inventory?
        self._weapon = weapon

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    @property
    def profession(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__

    @property
    def attack_power(self) -> int:
        return self._attack_power + self._weapon.attack_power

    @property
    def spell_power(self) -> int:
        return self._spell_power + self._weapon.spell_power

    @property
    def agility(self) -> int:
        return self._agility + self._weapon.agility

    @property
    def luck(self) -> int:
        return self._luck + self._weapon.luck


class Adventurer(HeroCharacter):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super().__init__(
            name=name,
            health_points=225,
            attack_power=30,
            spell_power=0,
            agility=30,
            luck=10,
        )


class Wizard(HeroCharacter):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super().__init__(
            name=name,
            health_points=175,
            attack_power=10,
            spell_power=75,
            agility=0,
            luck=4
        )


class Warrior(HeroCharacter):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super().__init__(
            name=name,
            health_points=250,
            attack_power=60,
            spell_power=5,
            agility=15,
            luck=4
        )


class Assassin(HeroCharacter):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super().__init__(
            name=name,
            health_points=200,
            attack_power=35,
            spell_power=15,
            agility=40,
            luck=4
        )
```

I've defined the attributes common to weapons as a `NamedTuple` because defining the names of the different attributes (rather than having them be string literals in a dictionary) means you're less likely to typo them -- if you're using an IDE, the names will even autocomplete for you because you've defined them ahead of time!  :)

To represent the concept of an equipped weapon I've added a `_weapon` attribute to the `HeroCharacter` class; to make the logic simpler, I'm representing the "unarmed" state as being a type of weapon, so that there is always a `Weapon` object that we can examine, even if the weapon is bare hands.

The effective stats of the character can then be computed `@property`s -- every time you say something like `player.attack_power` you get the answer that factors in the weapon's stats.

I've also simplified some other aspects of the character class hierarchy.  All of the parts of the initialization that are common to all the characters (like level and XP) have moved into the `HeroCharacter` base class.  The "profession" class variable isn't needed because you can get it from the name of the class.  I've also moved the `input()` call out of the constructor because having a constructor do something blocking like prompt for input is very likely to get annoying at some point (like when you want to, say, save progress to a file and then load it, in which case you wouldn't want to re-prompt the user for their character name).

Here's an example of using those properties and how `equip`ping a weapon changes their values:

```
>>> player = Assassin("Bob")
>>> player.name
'Bob'
>>> player.profession
'Assassin'
>>> player.equip(Weapon("starter_dagger", 4, 0, 10, 1, "Assassin starter weapon"))
>>> player.attack_power
39
>>> player.agility
50
>>> player.equip(Weapon("starter_longsword", 12, 0, -2, 2, "Unnecessarily heavy longsword"))
>>> player.attack_power
47
>>> player.agility
38
```

Comment: I thought the initial question was too broad, but now looking at your awesome answer I think maybe it's not. great job!

Comment: This seems solid! But you wouldn't use the equipment.py module then?
Seems like it's necessary to put in all the values, instead of just taking the key from the dictionary and then it would automatically add the values to the HeroCharacter stats :)

Comment: I think you could potentially go more generic with it, yeah -- define the attributes as an `Enum` and then define any piece of equipment as a collection of attribute:modifier mappings.  But that adds more complexity; given your example, it seems better to keep it simple and just explicitly define the modifiers for each weapon (this also helps you make sure you aren't forgetting to consider each attribute as you add new pieces of equipment).

Answer (score 1):

Cool question! It's very open-ended and there are a lot of decisions you get to make on how to handle weapons in your game.

Your question is really too open-ended though, as stack overflow is better suited to answering specific problems your facing. I'd suggest taking a stab at coming up with a solution yourself and then posting a new question if you get stuck.

With that said, I'd suggest starting simple and making a value to store a weapon in the character class and also making an "attack" function. Below is just pseudo-code to give you one possible idea

```
class HeroCharacter:
    def __init__(self, name, health_points, attack_power, spell_power, agility, inventory,
                 level, experience, luck):
        self.name = name
        self.health_points = health_points
        self.attack_power = attack_power
        self.spell_power = spell_power
        self.agility = agility
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.level = level
        self.experience = experience
        self.luck = luck

        self.weapon = None


    def get_attack_value(self):
        val = self.attack_power
        if self.weapon != None:
            val += self.weapon['attack_power']

        return val
```

Answer (score 0):

To class `HeroCharacter` add there two functions. But in every weapon you need to specify all stats(attack_power, spell_power, agility, luck itp. If weapon dose not use them just set them to 0). I also would add name of the weapon as a stat for easier accesing in `add_quipment`

```
class HeroCharacter:
        def __init__(self, name, health_points, attack_power, spell_power, agility, inventory,
                     level, experience, luck):
            self.name = name
            self.health_points = health_points
            self.attack_power = attack_power
            self.spell_power = spell_power
            self.agility = agility
            self.inventory = inventory
            self.level = level
            self.experience = experience
            self.luck = luck

    def add_equipment(self, eq):
        self.attack_power += eq["attack_power"]
        self.spell_power += eq["spell_power"]
        self.agility += eq["agility"]
        self.luck += eq["luck"]
        
    def del_equipment(self, eq):
        self.attack_power -= eq["attack_power"]
        self.spell_power -= eq["spell_power"]
        self.agility -= eq["agility"]
        self.luck -= eq["luck"]
```

To use these functions u will need to do this:

```
hero = HeroCharacter("Bob", 10, 10, 10, 10, "", 10, 10, 10) #Create your hero 

hero.add_equipment(weapons['starter_dagger']) #Select and add equ to hero

hero.del_equipment(weapons['starter_dagger']) # And use this to delete item from hero
```